# Using Terminal, How do I Uninstall Programs Included with the Ubuntu Installation? Apt-get isn't working!

Tags: command-line, apt, software-center, uninstall, software-uninstall

How do I use the **Terminal** to uninstall software (from the original 16.04 installation) found in Ubuntu Software?

Specifically

- Cheese
- All games
- Desktop Sharing
- File Sharing
- Rhythm Box
- Shotwell

I have several Ubuntu VM's to set up and I plan on running a script to uninstall the packages to avoid the buggy Ubuntu Software application and speed things up.

I tried using apt-get, dpkg, and aptitude to no avail.  All package managers would return "Package not found."  From my understanding, Ubuntu Software uses apt-get, so why is apt-get not working in the Terminal?
[image: Commands I tried]
Am I typing the package names wrong?
Are these programs in packages with different names?
I would rather not use a GUI application.

Comment: Do some research before removing software as broken dependencies will cause an unstable system. Have you tried synaptic package manger?

Comment: I suggest you to use Ubuntu 18.04 and minimal option while installing the system... it will removes everything except the desktop and some trivial packages.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy-paste the text, and use the formatting tools to make it look nice. (For details, see [Why do people post screenshots of their terminals?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/301745))

Comment: @Ravexina For 16.04, maybe OP could install the server version and just install the DE?

Comment: @wjandrea That's definitely an other option to consider however there might be some differences between some necessary stuff like networking I guess...

Comment: @steeldriver's answer is correct - the names of the programs you're typing in are the more readable forms for us users and not the actual names of the programs that are installed. I'd generally just use `sudo apt remove properpackagename` but you'll have to find out the proper 'computer names' of each program you want to remove. From the list, you shouldn't experience any problems removing those programs with the exception of 'file sharing' which *might* be tied to Nautilus (Files) - you'd be best to research that one before removing it just in case.

Comment: @Ravexina Thanks for the suggestion.  I had just found that option before I got back on and that solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dpkg command to remove the applications.
for example:

```
sudo dpkg -r cheese
```

Comment: If it is a snap package , then use  `sudo snap remove package name` . For example `sudo snap remove chromium`